# Is there a nice and clean way to handle multiple query params in Quarkus?

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm creating REST resources in Quarkus using Kotlin. Now I was wondering whether there's a nice and clean way to handle query params. I'm also using Hibernate Panache, and ideally I'd like to have something like this:

```
    @GET
    fun getAllCustomers(@Context uriInfo: UriInfo): List<Customer>? = customerRepository.list(uriInfo.queryParameters)
```

Would something like this be possible?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `@QueryParam` or does it fit your needs somehow?

Comment: I was wondering if there's a clean way to handle multiple query params, and how to handle somewhat more complex queries where some queries might not be included in the request from the front-end. Should I create a lot of safe calls and create a custopmerRepository.list("query", ...params) for each possible combination of query params?

Comment: There is no out of the box solution as far as I know